# Minor of matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, attributes

I'm writing in function for computing minor of matrix

```
def minor(arr,i,j):
    return arr[np.array(range(i)+range(i+1,arr.shape[0]))[:,np.newaxis],  
               np.array(range(j)+range(j+1,arr.shape[1]))]
```

And then apply it to an array which I initialized:

```
for row in values_float:
    for item in row:
        am[p][k] = item
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Does anybody know why I got it?

Answer (score 1):

`.shape` is an attribute of numpy arrays, while you apply it to a Python list. You can replace `arr.shape[0]` (and `arr.shape[1]`, respectively) with the dimension of the list that you are interested in (`i` or `j`, in your case).

Alternatively, you can initialise a numpy array from your `values_float` list, as such:

```
am = numpy.array(values_float, dtype=float)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to initialize an array in numpy is with numpy.ndarray or numpy.zeros instead of how you did and what you're initializing a list.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html

Answer (score 0):

A possible source for this error, in general:

in your class `MyClass`, in `__init__()`, you define an attribute `attr` for the instances of your class. In some method, you want to access this attribute. You call this method on a object of type `MyClass`, say `myObj`. But instead of doing myObj.attr, you are calling `MyClass.attr`. Your class has no attribute. Instances of the class do.

In your case, `shape` is an attribute of a `numpy` arrays, whereas your input object is a list.

Comment: @liubov dont see why this was downvoted. from what you explained at first, my general answer is a very likely cause for having this AttributeError. without more code (at the time of my post), it was much like a guess. i edited after you added the code.

Comment: The downvote couldn't have come from the OP, who doesn't have downvote privilege.  Probably someone came along after the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Is arr a 2-dimensional array? If you dont have numpy you could compute the minor like so:

```
def minor(arr, i, j):
    minor = [row[:j] + row[j+1:] for row in (arr[:i] + arr[i+1:])]
    return minor
```